# Find returns an empty array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make that if statement run if it can't find the url. But If the url does not exist it returns an empty array instead of an error. What is going on here?

```
function shortenURL() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1;
    console.log('Test');
    URL.find({short_url: 'https://nodejs-arun4033622.c9users.io/' + randomNumber}, (err, url) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Hey');
            var newURL = {
                original_url: req.params.url,
                short_url: 'https://nodejs-arun4033622.c9users.io/' + randomNumber
            }
            URL.create(newURL, (err, newurl) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    res.send(newurl);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(url);
            //shortenURL();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why would it send an error? Just because it didn't find something does not mean that it is considered an error. `if (err)` should be `if (!url.length)`. Also, `find` sends back an array of objects, not a single object, so grammatically it should be `urls`.

Comment: You're a life saver thank you so much!